# C-Segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, linux, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am new at coding so I know i may be messing up some things. I want to create an array of (number_of_text_words)x(number_of_letters_of each_word) dimensions, where i would save the words, character by character and putting '\0' in the end, so as to be recognised as a string. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *myinput;
    int i,k,sum,words_num,j;
    char **dict=NULL;
    char *num_words=NULL;
    myinput = fopen("bug.txt","r");
    if (myinput == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR:\n");
        return;
    }
    fseek(myinput,0,SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(myinput);
    fseek(myinput,0,SEEK_SET);
    char *data = malloc(size);
    if (data==NULL)
    return -1;
    fread(data,size,1,myinput);



    fclose(myinput);


    sum=0;
    for (i=0;i<=size-1;i++)
    if (data[i]=='\n')
    sum++;//count the words by the spaces


    /*for (i=0;i<=size-1;i++)
printf("%c\n",data[i]);*/

    /*printf("\n%d\n",sum);*/

    dict=malloc(sum);//for saving the words
    if (dict==NULL)
    return -1;
    num_words=malloc(sum);//for saving the number of letters of each word
    if (num_words==NULL)
    return -1;
    j=0;
    for (i=0;i<sum;i++){
        words_num=0;
        while ((data[j++]!='\n'))
        words_num++;//allocate the exact needed memory for each word



        dict[i]=malloc(words_num+1);//FOR THE FINAL '\0'
        if (dict[i]==NULL)
        return -1;
        num_words[i]=words_num;

    }

    k=0;
    for (i=0;i<sum;i++){
        for(j=0;j<num_words[i];j++){
            if ((data[k]=='\n') || (data[k]==EOF))
            k++;
            if (k<size)
            dict[i][j]=data[k++];
        }
        if (k<=size)
        dict[i][j+1]='\0';
    }



    for (i=0;i<sum;i++)
    free(dict[i]);

    free(dict);

    free(num_words);

    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

It cannot be compiled though,as it shows me a segmentation fault. More specific, -g compiling shows me the following:

> > *** Error in `./crossword': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000fdf010 ***
> >     ======= Backtrace: ========= /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f7b54dc87e5]
> >     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7f7b54dd137a]
> >     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f7b54dd553c]
> >     ./crossword[0x400a97]
> >     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f7b54d71830]
> >     ./crossword[0x400699]
> >     ======= Memory map: ======== 00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:25 532064
> >     /home/nikos/Desktop/ergasies/ergasia_4/crossword 00600000-00601000
> >     r--p 00000000 08:25 532064
> >     /home/nikos/Desktop/ergasies/ergasia_4/crossword 00601000-00602000
> >     rw-p 00001000 08:25 532064
> >     /home/nikos/Desktop/ergasies/ergasia_4/crossword 00fdf000-01000000
> >     rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
> >     7f7b50000000-7f7b50021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
> >     7f7b50021000-7f7b54000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
> >     7f7b54b3b000-7f7b54b51000 r-xp 00000000 08:25 529319
> >     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 7f7b54b51000-7f7b54d50000 ---p
> >     00016000 08:25 529319
> >     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 7f7b54d50000-7f7b54d51000 rw-p
> >     00015000 08:25 529319
> >     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 7f7b54d51000-7f7b54f11000 r-xp
> >     00000000 08:25 542663
> >     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so 7f7b54f11000-7f7b55111000 ---p
> >     001c0000 08:25 542663
> >     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so 7f7b55111000-7f7b55115000 r--p
> >     001c0000 08:25 542663
> >     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so 7f7b55115000-7f7b55117000 rw-p
> >     001c4000 08:25 542663
> >     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so 7f7b55117000-7f7b5511b000 rw-p
> >     00000000 00:00 0  7f7b5511b000-7f7b55141000 r-xp 00000000 08:25 542656
> >     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so 7f7b55323000-7f7b55326000 rw-p
> >     00000000 00:00 0  7f7b5533f000-7f7b55340000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
> >     7f7b55340000-7f7b55341000 r--p 00025000 08:25 542656
> >     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so 7f7b55341000-7f7b55342000 rw-p
> >     00026000 08:25 542656
> >     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so 7f7b55342000-7f7b55343000 rw-p
> >     00000000 00:00 0  7fff2dca9000-7fff2dcca000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
> >     [stack] 7fff2dd02000-7fff2dd05000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0
> >     [vvar] 7fff2dd05000-7fff2dd07000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
> >     [vdso] ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
> >     [vsyscall] Aborted (core dumped)

i also created an array for saving each words size. I did not double freed any pointer, nor can I find any "out-of-array' writing. Can anyone point the things that are going wrong in my code?Would really appreciate it:)

Comment: Be consistent with your own coding style, and format your code so that it's readable. Specially, when you intend to show it to others. Oh, and usually `for (i=0;i<=size-1;i++)` we right it like this `for (i = 0; i < size; i++)`.

Comment: A Segfault means that you/your program probably try to acccess a memory location which does not deserve you. Think of that.

Comment: I see you've already got an answer, but I am still not clear on the problem. Your error spew seems to indicate that you did compile and run your application, but you problem statement says it did not compile.  Which is it?

Comment: no,no,i did not manage to compile because i had not alloc'd enough space for the array of pointers(aka dict). now i am set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allocating enough space, here

```
dict=malloc(sum);
```

should be

```
dict = malloc(sum * sizeof(*dict));
```

Because you need `sum` elements of size `void *`, but it's better to write `sizeof(*dict)`, because that way the code is independent on the type of `dict`, and if you change it you don't need to fixe your `malloc()`.

This also looks suspicious,

```
num_words=malloc(sum);
```

how do you know that there are as many characters for every word as lines there were in the file?

Comment: oh my god, i have been looking at my code for 2 days and it was this. i thought i was lacking much more significant knowledge. you relieved me a lot. really thanks for lending me a pair of eyes on this!

Comment: @NikosNik You're welcome. If you use a programmer friendly operating system that has [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) support, you can further check your code for more problems, some of which can be very hard to find. Also, use more whitespace, `dict=malloc ...` is horrible style. The compiler can immediatly see that there are 3 "*tokens*" in `dict=malloc`, but humans could need a little bit more attention to notice that.

Comment: yeah,thanks for the info. i will try to improve code's appearance. used valgrind before asking but could not reach to the solution